# Webhook Body JSON for TMSL Script

Tags: json, azure-powershell

I'm trying to put a TMSL script into a Webhook Body so that it can be passed to an Azure Runbook Powershell Script, and used to refresh a table in the Power BI Service.

Could someone help turn the TMSL script into a valid JSON for this operation?

It needs to fit inside:

```
{
"Query": "TMSL Script"
}
```

And the TMSL script is:

```
{
  "refresh": {
    "type": "full",
    "objects": [
      {
        "database": "DATABASE NAME",
        "table": "TABLE NAME"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried many combinations of moving the speech marks, but cannot seem to find the right one seeing as the script is already in JSON format. I currently have the TMSL script hard coded in Powershell and it works.

The TMSL script in Powershell is:

```
"{
    ""refresh"": {
    ""type"": ""full"",
    ""objects"": [
        {
            ""database"": ""DATABASE NAME"",
            ""table"": ""TABLE NAME""
        }
      ]
   }
}"
```